# sbt console - set scala-version for all sub-projects

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-project build with `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"` for each module.

I want to run `test` and `publish-local` for Scala 2.12.0-RC1 without touching the build file. I thought the following would work:

```
$ sbt
> set scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.0-RC1"
> test
```

But that does not alter the Scala version used, sbt still compiles with Scala 2.11.8. This only works for single module builds (without `project` definitions).

How do I effectively override `scalaVersion` for all sub-modules from the sbt console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't work because the setting for the module takes priority over the setting for `ThisBuild`; it would work if you used `scalaVersion in ThisBuild` in the build file instead of setting it separately for each module. I don't know if there is a way to do this with anything *except* `scalaVersion`, but:

> [As a final note, you can use ++  to temporarily switch the Scala version currently being used to build.  should be either a version for Scala published to a repository, as in ++ 2.10.0 or the path to a Scala home directory, as in ++ /path/to/scala/home. See Command Line Reference for details.](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html)

```
> ++2.12.0-RC1
> test
```